# Qt + Android - Writing to a network location

Tags: android, c++, qt

I currently have a Qt Application that writes to a log during use and saves the file locally to the device.

This is straightforward enough, I create a QFile with the local path and write to it.

It looks something like this:

```
QFile logFile;
QString logPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
logFile.setFileName(logPath.append("/MyLogFile.txt"));
logFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Append);
// Write to log file ...
```

This works fine but I'd like to also write this log file to a network drive - 
E.g. `//192.168.12.34/Drive-1/LogFile.txt`

I've tried altering the path to `//192.168.12.34/Drive-1`
 but see nothing new in the network folder when I navigate to the above  on a desktop.

Is this something that's possible to do from an Android device?

Comment: What kind of network drive is it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the different kinds of drives are - physically its a USB stick plugged into a router (http://us.dlink.com/products/business-solutions/unified-services-router-2/), they refer to it as a Shareport. If you need further info just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done this way. You need to mount the network drive first using a samba client, and then copy the files.

You can use a samba client app like [AndSMB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb&hl=es) thats allow folder synchronization for that.